# Positioning Labels in Different Devices

Tags: autolayout, label, image-resizing, size-classes

I'm design an app that loads a huge vertical image into a scrollView. This Image has some pre-written text (just to minimize the number of labels in Interface Builder) and i want to print content to some UIlabels.
The problem i'm face is: When i change the Device type, my labels don't follows the image behind, because of the label's constant auto layouts constrains.
So i tried to re-positioning the labels in code, checking with a switch case in viewDidAppear() method, for the Width of the screen, then moving the label to the desired position in Height. It worked, but as soon i scrolled the view, all the Labels came back to his "original" place. I didn't get what was wrong with it. Should be the constrains taking control again?

I would like to know what would be the most proper way to do this, as auto layout works with size classes and not Devices. 
Any idea will help.

Here's some screens to illustrate better what i'm facing:

[image: Right Way]
This is the iPhone 6Plus View - RIGHT

[image: Wrong Way]
This is the iPhone 5S View - WRONG

Comment: I think the whole idea of loading the image with text into a scrollView is terrible. Why not use UITableView? It is ideal for this kind of layout.

Comment: I started using the image because of the app visual identity. But i'm really thinking in the tableView option right now. Thanks

Comment: UITableView is very customizable, you can easily make it look like in your screenshot, or better.